# How do I see if I'm hitting my API rate limit in google sheets / gsuite?

Tags: api, google-workspace

I'm getting some errors on some of the API calls that certain google sheets are setup with. I want to make sure I'm not reaching my limit.

Is there anywhere i can see if I'm reaching my API call limit within g suite?

Answer (score 1):

Exceeding a rate limit will cause an HTTP 403 or HTTP 429 `Too Many Requests` response and your app should respond by retrying with exponential backoff.

To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:

1. If you don't already have a billing account for your project, then create one.
2. Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
3. To view and change quota-related settings, select Quotas. To view usage statistics,       select Usage.

From: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota